# Instalar una libreria externa Allegro

Tags: c++, c

Hola Queria hacerles unas pregunta

1. ¿Que es lo que necesito para usar una libreria externa?
2. ¿Cual es la diferencia entre el fuente de allegro y el binario no se
   si sere muy ignorante pero si yo le paso el compilador al codigo
   fuente funciona?

Yo intente instalar el allegro como me sale en Aqui [guia de instalacion](https://wiki.allegro.cc/index.php?title=Windows,_Code::Blocks_and_Allegro_5)
Pero cuando descargo el allegro-5.2.5.0.zip
no encuentro las carpetas que deberian de estar adentro

Comment: Buenas Israel. Bienvenido a [es.so]. Lamentablemente, las preguntas que realizas implican que estás intentando hacer algo para lo que aún no tienes la formación suficiente.
Ya está respondida la pregunta de "¿qué necesito para usar una librería externa?".
Además, la pregunta "diferencias entre código fuente y binario" es lo primero que aprendes al realizar cualquier curso de programación en C o C++. Así que te recomiendo que empieces por ahí primero, antes de meterte a manosear la librería Allegro.

Answer (score 0):

Necesitas instalar MinGW, este programa no solo instalara Allegro, sino también las librerías necesarias para utilizar C/C++ debiste de haberlo instalado antes si estas usando C. Ahora dentro del programa debes buscar Allegro y marcar su instalación. Y compilar un programa de prueba en una IDE (de C) para comprobar que están dichas librerías. Esto no debería de generar errores como el de, no existe tal función etc.
La diferencia entre el código fuente y el código binario es que en el fuente usas letras en el binario usas solo dos dígitos: 1 y 0 tal cual la computadora entiende: 1010011100101010101.